# Setting object as key for map and accessing assigned values

Tags: javascript

Suppose the following:

```js
const socketTracker = new Map();

const addToSocketTracker = ({ userId, socketId }) => {
  socketTracker.set({
      socketId,
      userId
  }, {
      sendMessage: function() {
        return [`Socket ID: ${this.socketId}`, `User ID: ${this.userId}`].join('\n')
      }
  });
}

addToSocketTracker({ userId: 123, socketId: 456 })

const element = socketTracker.get(({ userId }) => userId === 123); // this returns undefined
element?.sendMessage();

console.log('element', element);
```

Is it possible to access a specific key and then call `sendMessage` as in the snippet?

Comment: [`Map`'s `get` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) does not take a function. Try passing the object directly? `socketTracker.get({ userId, socketId })`?

Comment: Doesn't work that way either

Comment: Why make the `socketId` part of the *key* of the map? Your lookup is just by `userId`, so normally I'd expect to just use the `userId` as the key.

Comment: That's probably because `{} !== {}`. Try passing the same object (variable) into both `addToSocketTracker` and `socketTracker.get`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's just an example, suppose it to be some other arbitrary property instead

Comment: @evolutionxbox The idea is to potentially retrieve an element from the map at any other point in the future lifecycle of the program, where the variable will not exist

Comment: Provided the example, the only way is to iterate over the entires until you find yours. `socketTracker.entries().find(([key, value]) => key.userId === 123)`

Comment: @MikeK - It doesn't make sense to key a map by anything other than what you're going to use to look up entries: `userId` in this case. Without a concrete example and explanation, only mediocre, probably-incomplete answers can be offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to access a specific key and then call `sendMessage`?

It *is*, but it's not efficient. You have to loop through the map's keys:¹

```
const key = [...socketTracker.keys()].find(({ userId }) => userId === 123);
const element = key ? socketTracker.get(key) : undefined;
element?.sendMessage();
```

In the given example, though, I don't see any reason for `socketId` to be part of the *key* of the map. Fundamentally, key a map by what you're going to use to look up its entries: just `userId`, in this case. If you *also* need to look up entries by `socketId`, you can have a separate map for that. Or if you need a compound key, you can use a map of maps.

In particular, it doesn't make sense to key a map by an object unless you will later have a reference to *that **same** object* to use to look up the map entry, since `Object.is({}, {})` is `false` — no object is *equal* to any other object.

---

A couple of notes on that:

1. You can avoid the intermediate array by writing a simple utility function to do a `find`-like operation on an iterable. Iterables are getting `find`, though: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers.
2. And I guess technically you don't need that conditional operator if you never use `undefined` as a key, just `const element = socketTracker.get(key);` would also work, giving you `undefined` for `element` when `key` was `undefined`.

Comment: Makes sense, I suppose. I guess I just don't see a point in being able to use objects or functions as keys in Javascript maps, then

Comment: @MikeK - It's for situations where you really will have a reference to that object from elsewhere. But yeah, they're rare. :-) (More common with `WeakMap` than with `Map`.)

Answer (score 1):

`socketTracker.get(({ userId }) => userId === 123)` - you are trying to get element like with an `Array::filter()`. `Map::get()` actually accepts a key, not a callback.

`Map()` isn't good for this scenario, use `Array()`:

```js
const socketTracker = [];

const addToSocketTracker = ({ userId, socketId }) => {
  socketTracker.push({
      socketId,
      userId,
      sendMessage: function() {
        console.log( [`Socket ID: ${this.socketId}`, `User ID: ${this.userId}`].join('\n'));
      }
  });
}

addToSocketTracker({ userId: 123, socketId: 456 })

socketTracker.filter(({ userId }) => userId === 123).forEach(socket => socket.sendMessage());
```

Basically you are trying to use denormalized data where you have users with sockets. So better restructure (normalize) your data and make sockets as a part of a user object:

```js
const socketTracker = new Map;

const addToSocketTracker = ({ userId, socketId }) => {
  let user = socketTracker.get(userId);
  if(!user){
    socketTracker.set(userId, {
      sockets:[socketId], 
      sendMessage: function() {
        this.sockets.forEach(socket => console.log( [`Socket ID: ${socket}`, `User ID: ${userId}`].join('\n')));
      }
    });
  } else {
    user.sockets.push(socketId);
  }
  
}

addToSocketTracker({ userId: 123, socketId: 456 })

socketTracker.get(123).sendMessage();
```